# Meaning of a landslide president?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "I went to the station to fetch my wife and was greeted by the press like a rock star - landslide president - first moonwalker all in one".

I know what a landslide is, but I have absolutely no idea what it means in this context... I also tried googling this expression to see if it's some sort of idiom but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: "I know what a landslide is,"   Since landslide has multiple meanings, it is possible that you don't know what "a landslide" is... SO please edit to tell us what you think it means (in this context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/landslide), landslide is defined as

> A vote won by a wide or overwhelming majority.
>
> > The candidate won by a landslide.

We can have [a landslide victory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landslide_victory) meaning one candidate or party received an overwhelming majority of the votes or seats in the elected body.

> [Americans are about to get the first landslide president we don’t want](https://nypost.com/2016/08/20/americans-are-about-to-get-the-first-landslide-president-we-dont-want/)

Answer (score 0):

A "landslide" in politics is when a candidate wins by an overwhelming majority of votes in an election.

A 'landslide president' would be one whom the majority of people voted for, and you would expect (in theory) be popular with a majority.

You would have found this answer in a dictionary. Most dictionaries place *literal* definitions first. It should be quite obvious from the context that this is a metaphor (he isn't sliding down any land) and you will find it as a secondary definition in most good dictionaries.